# SSL/TLS certificate progress application

Tags: ssl-certificate, tls1.2, openedge, progress-4gl

We have a server which is an azure APIM and a client which is built on OpenEdge (progress)
I've learnt that if the server certificate chain is properly set up and the client has the root certificate, this is enough for the client to validate the server.

However it seems OpenEdge (progress) doesn't use the OS's functionality (yet). So we need to "tell" OpenEdge exactly what is trusted, which is resulting in certificate issue , even though the client has the root certificate, and the server has a proper certificate chain setup.

Is this really true? does OpenEdge (progress) really behave this way ? or have I been missleaded ?

already described above

Answer (score 0):

It is true that if you have things properly setup that the client will be able to validate the server and it is true that OpenEdge does not use "OS functionality" to decide who to trust. You do have to tell OE very specifically what certificates you trust.  The -certstorepath startup parameter is very helpful for this purpose.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more how the certstorepath  can help solve the problem ?

Comment: Generally speaking it allows you to easily add missing certificates. You haven't actually defined "the problem" or even shared an actual error message but, typically, there is a disconnect of some kind between the certificates that are trusted. Often because the certificates that come with your particular OpenEdge have expired or don't match the certificates that the server trusts.

Comment: I guess I want clear enough. My question was more on whether this is a limitation of the openedge progress application, that it has to be told explicitly which certificate to trust and it does not use the OS functionality. If the same application would have been built in some other technology lets say java and spring, then this would work without having to explicitly specify which certificate to trust ?

Comment: I'm still not sure what problem you're having and what OS functionality you'd like to rely on but, personally, I don't view the need to be specific about which certificates my application will trust as a "limitation". I see that as being more of a "feature".

Answer (score 0):

For OpenEdge applications, typically you need to import (register) the root CA certificates into the OpenEdge certificate store, using the [`certutil -import`](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-install-117/page/certutil.html) command.